# is there a alternative for .firstChild JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tic-tac-toe

instead of using .firstChild, i want it to be more specific and see if xmark is there. but slots[0] === xMark doesn't work... is there a way to do this ?

i'm trying to make it so that when a

```
// if first three arrays has the appendchild(xMark in it ), i should win the match.
slots.forEach(slot => {
    slot.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const xMark = document.createElement('img');
        xMark.setAttribute('src', './assets/icon-x.svg');
        slot.appendChild(xMark)

        if(slots[0].firstChild  && slots[1].firstChild &&  slots[2].firstChild ){
            console.log('u won')
        } else {
            'error'
        }
        
    }); 
    
});
```

Comment: It would be better to store your board data in an array rather than have your source of truth be the DOM. If you go this route, one way to check is if your element [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) an img element with `slots[0].querySelector('img')` which will return `null` if nothing is found.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090374/is-there-a-alternative-for-firstchild-javascript#comment130814039_74090374) "_It would be better to store your board data in an array rather than have your source of truth be the DOM_": @AndyRay That makes sense if the DOM is being treated as an artifact of program state in one-way data flow (e.g. React), but the OP didn't mention anything like that. I'm curious — why do you say that?

Comment: @jsejcksn It makes sense not just in react, but in all web applications. Separate the model from the view.